# how to distinguish 0 and NULL in c++

Tags: c++

how to distinguish 0 and NULL in c++? I only want
 to print when the element is realy NULL but not 0.

```
vector<int> vec = {0, NULL};
for (auto it : vec){
    if (it == NULL) cout << "NULL";
}
```

actually i want to use NULL to represent the NULL node in the binary tree (input as a vector). If i use "NULL", then the input cannot be simply vector, is there any proper way to solve it?

Comment: `int` can’t be null. It’s an integral type. So the definition of null is exactly the same as 0 in that case. This is also why `nullptr` exists, it would give you an error trying to put it to an integral type.

Comment: `NULL` is literally defined in most header files as `#define NULL 0` or some variation of `((void*)0`.  So...

Comment: What are really trying to do? Do you want an array of integers where certain items can be marked as invalid?

Comment: @acraig5075 pls see the update

Comment: Elaborate about the relation between your vector and your binary tree. I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There is no such thing as an "invalid" integer.

Comment: `::std::vector<::std::optional<int>>`

Comment: why don't you use 0 for the "NULL node"?

Comment: THough NULL is implementation-specific, it will be mostly be implemented as a `#define NULL 0` so in your code you can `#undef NULL` and define it to a different value differentiating it from `0`

Comment: @Sisir That would break every use of `NULL` to represent a null pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not necessarily, if he reverts back the value to `0` after the use

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#. **There are no null objects here.** `NULL` is just an old way of indicating an invalid pointer address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int can't be `nullptr`,  because it's an integer type.

You are using a macro so `NULL` will be substitued with 0. So you are actually checking if the value of the vector for each element is equal to zero.

if you want to check for null pointer you should use the **keyword** `nullptr` instead of the **macro** `NULL`.

If you want to store pointer you have to use `vector<int*>`. In that case you can easily check for null with a simple

`if(!ptr)`  <-- if pointer is not null

or

`if( ptr == nullptr )` which is exactly the same.

As additional note, you are copying each element when looping your array, you should use `const auto&` (or `auto&`) instead.

Comment: @user6703592 my answer already is an answer to your problem, read the part of vector pointer.

Comment: A null pointer doesn't necessarily contain zero. It's not even necessary that all types of null pointers have the same representation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way. In this context, NULL is replaced with 0 everywhere. The compiler treats NULL as exactly the same as 0.

Comment: Perhaps you should delete this question and try again, asking the question you actually want answered.